# ERROR - Cannot invoke initializer for type 'LineChartData' with an argument list of type '(xVals: [String], dataSet: LineChartDataSet)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, graph

I am currently using the [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) framework to use a line graph within my app. I have used the code below but an error is occurring. Here is the code-

```
`func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: Double(i))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)


    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }



        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")

        let lineChartDataa = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)

    Graph.data = lineChartDataa

}
`
```

The error that is occurring is below-

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'LineChartData' with an argument list of type '(xVals: [String], dataSet: LineChartDataSet)'

Any ideas how I could fix this.

Comment: What's the function signature ? ( cmd+click)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this :

This is to set `LineChartData`:

```
let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")     
let lineChartDataa = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
```

For setting xAxis labels :

```
Graph.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
Graph.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)
```

Answer (score 0):

[LineChartData](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/a540403f0d531f29ce01007dbccf2d6a26ad8253/Source/Charts/Data/Implementations/Standard/LineChartData.swift) has declared this as init.

```
public override init(dataSets: [IChartDataSet]?)
```

Its superclass, [ChartData](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/e47f8c41a9b4f8864365e8cc05c32a28a781fc70/Source/Charts/Data/Implementations/Standard/ChartData.swift) has declared these inits:

```
@objc public init(dataSets: [IChartDataSet]?)


@objc public convenience init(dataSet: IChartDataSet?)
```

It looks like the init with params that you are trying, is not available, hence the compiler error.